# Google App Engine + WTP + Java 7

Tags: google-app-engine

I've a question about using google app engine on Eclipse with java 7.
I'm using maven (that is officially supported), and I'm using Eclipse WTP to run my application.

My problem is that if I use Java 6 on my project all works well, but if I try to use java 7 I'm unable to run the application. When I try to add the application on my local server (doing run as->run on server or with the "add and remove" funcion of the local server) Eclipse say to me that java 7 is not supported

Is this a known issue o what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse WTP and Maven as well should have no issue with Java 7. Please copy paste the complete exact message you see.
I am sure there is some hidden settings somewhere causing you trouble, but java7 just works fine with App Engine, WTP and or Maven and Eclipse. I use it all the time.

Comment: Yes, it was only a problem with my eclipse. Sincerly, I don't know what problem was. I have completely removed Eclipse and than reinstalled it and all plugins.
And now all works well...
thanks anyway!